# CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to access this resource

Tags: lambda, serverless-framework

I have been following https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/create-a-cognito-user-pool.html this tutorial to create a react app that connects to an authenticated API. All of it is working fine with the exception of authenticating via the API. I’ve setup the Cognito User pool, Identity Pool and client ID. I’m able to login via the app but I keep getting the error below:

> **CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to access this resource**

My config for the API is:

```
Policies:
        - PolicyName: 'CognitoAuthorizedPolicy'
            PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: 'Allow'
                Action:
                  - 'mobileanalytics:PutEvents'
                  - 'cognito-sync:*'
                  - 'cognito-identity:*'
                    Resource: '*'

              # Allow users to invoke our API
              - Effect: 'Allow'
                Action:
                  - 'execute-api:Invoke'
                Resource:
                  Fn::Join:
                    - ''
                    -
                      - 'arn:aws:execute-api:'
                      - Ref: AWS::Region
                      - ':'
                      - Ref: AWS::AccountId
                      - ':'
                      - Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
                      - '/*'
```

I’m not sure what else I need to add to my serverless.yml. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your question on the serverless forums and added an answer there, will duplicate it here.

I think the issue is that execute-api API Gateway permissions are more complicated than that. They have the form `arn:aws:execute-api:region:account-id:api-id/stage-name/HTTP-VERB/resource-path` and last time I tried something like this, a wildcard right after the `api-id` portion was not enough. 
So you probably want something like

```
Fn::Join:
  - ''
  -
    - 'arn:aws:execute-api:'
    - Ref: AWS::Region
    - ':'
    - Ref: AWS::AccountId
    - ':'
    - Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
    - '/'
    - ${self:provider.stage} (or wherever you get your serverless stage variable from)
    - '/'
    - '*'
    - '/'
    - '*'
```

Don't quote me on this, but I also think that if your `resource-path` also has / in it, then you need to build out the permission so that it has the same number of / as your resource. So if your API has a GET and POST to /x/y/z then the policy statement would have to look like `arn:aws:execute-api:region:account-id:api-id/stage-name/*/*/*/*`. I vaguely remember having to have permissions like

```
arn:aws:execute-api:region:account-id:api-id/stage-name/*/*
arn:aws:execute-api:region:account-id:api-id/stage-name/*/*/*
arn:aws:execute-api:region:account-id:api-id/stage-name/*/*/*/*
etc
```

to match the levels in all my resources. I could be wrong though so YMMV

See:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html#arn-syntax-apigateway
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-iam-policy-examples-for-api-execution.html

Comment: Looks like I have some reading to do... I made the change and got the same outcome.

Comment: Could you share what the API Gateway resource you are trying to access looks like and what the generated IAM authenticated role policy looks like?